# Typer - group \ inheritance arguments

Tags: python, argparse, typer

I have several commands in the same typer app that get the same params or at least some of them (e.g. database connection arguments), but they are not sub-commands of each other.

I want to avoid copy-pasting those arguments for each command but rather define some sort of inheritance or grouping of arguments.

Bonus point - is there something similar to argparse [mutually exclusive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) groups in typer?

Comment: By coincidence, I'm looking for exactly this too.  The best I've found so far is somewhat verbose ... https://jacobian.org/til/common-arguments-with-typer/

Comment: Thanks @wally, getting closer but I feel it is not yet there

Comment: Agreed, it feels awkward and like a hack to me.  I'm keeping a keen eye on this thread - I'd dearly like to know a clean answer myself!